# Change code to list comprehension

Tags: python

I have wrote following code for a simple problem in Python -

```
def Peu1(numbers):
    "Sum of all the multiples of 3 or 5 below 1000."
    for num in range(numbers):
        if num%3 == 0 or num%5 == 0:
            test = sum(range(numbers),0)
        return test

print Peu1(1000)
```

I want to change it to List comprehension, I wrote following -

```
test = [sum(range(numbers),0) for num in range(numbers) if num%3 == 0 or num%5 == 0]
print test
```

but my list comprehension is printing result in a loop, I mean I am getting result n times(mod 3 or 5). Please pinpoint the mistake and guide.

Comment: Your `Peu1` function returns value after 1st iteration. Is an indention correct?

Comment: your original code doesn't work (at least two bugs, one conceptual)

Comment: Can you please point these issues, will help me understand.

Comment: Also, you code is completely wrong and won't solve Project Euler 1. You are assigning the `test` variable multiple times with a wrong value.

Comment: Got it, changed test = sum(range(numbers),0) to test += num, getting the right answer now.Thanks a lot @rubik

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A list comprehension is designed to build up a list - if you are not doing that, then you don't need to use one.

You could, however, use a list comprehension or generator expression inside your function, to generate the list of numbers to use:

```
sum(num for num in range(numbers) if num%3 == 0 or num%5 == 0)
```

Note that `numbers` is a bit of a misleading variable name - it would imply to me that it contained the range of numbers, I'd suggest either passing in the range of numbers, or calling it `highest` or something.

Rather than using the or with the same value, some people find something like `if 0 in {num%3, num%5}` clearer, personally, I think in this case it obscures the meaning a little.

Comment: if 0 in {num%3,num%5} , is it a short form for 'or', if yes, what is the short form for 'and' operation?

Comment: @Varun: That's not a short form for `or`, it is a short form for `num % 3 == 0 or num % 5 == 0`. It simply checks that in the set there is a 0. There is not a short form for `and`. There is, however, an alternative form for `num % 3 == 0 and num % 5 == 0`: `num % 15 == 0` (or `(num % 3, num % 5) == (0, 0)` which is ugly).

Comment: +1 to what rubik said - there are many ways of replacing the `or` operation in this case, for example `not all({num%3, num%5})` - it's just about replacing the logic with equivalent operation. When in doubt, stick to the obvious. Readable is better than short.

Comment: @Varun:  it is not short form for or. Also you should be aware that creating a tuple evaluates both expressions every time, while `all` and `any` stop evaluation of the expression as soon as possible.

Comment: `sum(set(range(0, numbers, 3)) | set(range(0, numbers, 5)))` ;)

Comment: @KarlKnechtel: According to `timeit`, it's 198% faster (with `range` in 2.x) with `xrange` in 2.x, it's 233% faster :)

Comment: The primary trick is to not generate the non-divisible numbers in the first place. Another way is `sum(range(0, numbers, 3)) + sum(range(0, numbers, 5)) - sum(range(0, numbers, 15))`.